# AWS EC2 multiple NIC routing

Tags: amazon-web-services, networking, amazon-ec2

I have currently three tomcat servers running off of Apache which listens to certain IP address each on one machine to redirect to certain routes. I want to move them up to AWS VPC for higher redundancy. Can i have three NICs on an instance that act the same as my prem version? How do i get the NAT up and running like my router does for the websites?

example:

```
eth0 = root.test.com 192.168.0.20/32 to 81.100.10.2, 
eth1 = stage.test.com 192.168.0.21/32 to 81.100.10.3, 
eth2 = test.root.com  92.168.0.22/32 to 81.100.10.4
```

Comment: This question doesn't appear to be programming-related. You might try ServerFault.

Comment: With current cloud technologies, where IT assets are provisioned as virtualized /software resources which can well be considered "software tools commonly used by programmers", this question may still be ok for StackOverflow.

Answer (score 0):

You can create and attach more than one EIN per instance. See limits here:

https://docs.aws.amazon.com/AWSEC2/latest/UserGuide/using-eni.html#AvailableIpPerENI

You can then route to these ENIs however you like, just reference them in your route tables. Recall each VPC has a default route table, but you can have additional route tables at the subnet level. Create two subnets one public, one private, place your NAT Gateway on your public subnet, and route all internet traffic from the private subnet through your NAT Gateway.

For a subnet to be public, we need to attach an Internet Gateway (IGW) to the VPC and update the route table of the public subnet to send non-local traffic to the IGW.